# How to select everything Lens Flare filter has added to the image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, selections, cc-2014, filter

How to make a selection of the flare that was added by Lens Flare filter in Photoshop CC 2014? Is there an automated way to do it?

I want to be able to mask the flare and tint it with blue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate the lens flare on a separate layer. This way you have full control over the flare size, pozition, color etc.

Comment: what do you mean by new layer? cause the filter can't run on empty layer, do you mean duplicating the background for example?

Comment: @akram Fill your layer with 50% Gray (Shift+F5), then generate the flare and set the layer mode to Linear Light.